Current Flowing Through Disabled NPN Transistor in Reverse?
I'm working on designing a circuit which involves NPN transistors, and I'm running into an interesting phenomenon that I don't quite understand; I'm observing current flowing in reverse direction through an NPN transistor with no voltage supplied to the gate if the collector sees a negative voltage.

Here's a simplified circuit that shows this phenomenon well, created in the Falstad Circuit Simulator:

Here's the circuit which can be loaded into the Falstad Circuit Simulator:
$ 1 0.000005 10.20027730826997 52 5 43 5e-11
g 272 352 272 368 0 0
r 272 288 272 352 0 100
w 288 288 272 288 0
w 400 208 240 208 0
t 400 272 400 288 1 1 0.5697380375409915 -0.36844030221061913 100 default
r 400 208 400 272 0 1000
172 224 288 192 288 0 7 3.3 3.3 0 0 0.5 Voltage
w 272 288 256 288 0
w 224 208 240 208 0
L 224 208 192 208 0 0 false 3.3 0
r 240 272 240 208 0 1000
t 240 272 240 288 1 1 -3.299999996598321 -0.07368805741115361 100 default
g 416 288 432 288 0 0
c 288 288 368 288 4 0.00009999999999999999 1.0118664005644433 0.001 0
w 368 288 384 288 0
o 13 64 0 4099 2.5 0.4 0 2 13 3

Paying close attention to the wire between the right-most NPN transistor's collector and the 100 uF capacitor, we observe that, upon charging the capacitor by setting the digital input pin to HIGH, and then setting the digital input pin to LOW, that wire suddenly experiences a negative voltage. The right-most transistor is disabled, as there is no voltage supplied to it's gate by the digital input pin, yet there are electrons flowing into right-most transistor's collector pin, and the capacitor is slowly drained... (the simulator clip below shows the electron flow through the wires, not the current flow, and highlights the wires with the voltage they're experiencing with green/red for positive/negative voltage)

I only have a very basic understanding of electronics, and as far as I understand an NPN transistor will let current flow from the collector to the emitter (electrons flowing from emitter to collector) only if there is a positive voltage supplied to it's gate. Hence, reverse current flow in a disabled transistor with a negative voltage seen by the collector here is very strange.

To confirm whether this is a bug of the circuit simulator, I built such a circuit on a physical breadboard:

With BC337 NPN transistors, and the digital input pin being IO pin 20 on a Teensy 4.0 microcontroller.

Surprisingly, a simillar behaviour is observed in this circuit as well, where the capacitor slowly discharges through the collector of the disabled NPN transistor (the multimeter is tracking the potential difference between the side of the capacitor facing the right-most transistor's collector and a ground).

What exactly is going on here? Why is current allowed to flow in reverse through a disabled NPN transistor if it's collector sees a negative voltage?
My goal here is to not have that capacitor discharge itself when the digital input pin is set to a LOW. I assumed that a disabled NPN transistor would not allow any current to flow through it in any direction, but there is clearly something else going on here that I'm not yet familliar with.
Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Bipolar (NPN & PNP) transistors have a base pin, not a gate. Field Effect Transistors (FETs) have a gate.

If you forward-bias the base-collector junction of a transistor, current will flow. That's what you're doing with the charge on the capacitor. When your digital input is high, the capacitor is charged to a couple of volts. When your digital input is low, the 100 Ω pulldown pulls the left end of the capacitor to 0 volts, so the right end becomes negative. This forward-biases the right-hand transistor's B-C junction.
There is also "reverse active" mode of a BJT. The transistor is a physically symmetric structure, and to a certain extent, the collector and emitter functions can be swapped. The performance isn't as good because they're doped differently, but it can still exhibit transistor action. As a result, much of the collector current flows through the emitter as well.

I see, that makes sense to me. Interestingly, putting a diode between the capacitor and the collector of the right-most transistor will stop the negative voltage from being drained from the capacitor, but it will keep that negative voltage in there forever... is there a way of making this work with something other than NPN transistors?

You haven't described what you're actually trying to accomplish here, so I can't advise you on that.

"My goal here is to not have that capacitor discharge itself when the digital input pin is set to a LOW." (last paragraph of my post)

But you said that adding a diode accomplishes that. Then you asked "is there a way of making this work?", which implies that you want something different. I'm confused.

"Disabled" is not one of the operating modes of a BJT. An NPN BJT with the collector more negative than the emitter, and with the base-collector junction forward biased, is in the reverse active mode. Basically, the emitter and collector change roles. A transistor operating in such a mode has a much lower beta than one operating in forward active mode.
Also, BJTs do not have "gates". They have bases.

This is expected behaviour.

using a push-pull with a  100 ohm grounded load on C+ and on C- the collector switches off dropping the collector below ground until it conducts again. This makes Vcb a forward diode and now the cap has low impedance on both ends, so it discharges exponentially slower.

Define your expectations for C+ and C- first then design a solution. ( in terms of V & Z) Then verify your results.
Keep in mind transistors normally have a reverse Beta around 1 but there are exceptions.
